# How to update a table from values on other table using sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 2 tables **mainacc** and **creditacc** .i need to update balance on **mainacc** based on value of **creditacc**.how can i do that???

```
mainacc(accno,balance)
creditacc(accno,balance)
```

where accno in creditacc is a foreign key.

Comment: Post your code so we can see the problem. What have you already tried?

Comment: Show your sample data along with your expected ouput

Comment: These 2 tables seem to exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

Use an update join, something similar to this:

```
UPDATE mainacc a
INNER JOIN creditacc b
    ON a.accno = n.accno
SET a.balance = b.balance;
```

If you instead want to adjust the balance of the main accounts based on the credit table, then you could use:

```
SET a.balance = a.balance + b.balance
```